# How to make cv2.filter2D faster?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filter, object-detection

I'm working on a project where i have to detect and track small cars using colors as feature representation of the object (see below image). For detection, I used histogram back_projection
See: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/df6/tutorial_py_histogram_backprojection.html

[image]

For Tracking i used KCF (Kernalized Correlation Filter)

If we look at the steps of the detection algorithm, it applies `cv2.filter2D` function along with some mohplogical operation such as Opening, Closing, etc after obtaining a probability distributed binary image in order to improve detection and remove noise.

When i run the code, i noticed that when detection occurs (every 20 frame), the process slightly hangs or become at the detection moment slow.

The code that is responsible for detection is:

```
def back_projectcam1(histm,hsv_histt,hsvt): #hist: model histogram, hsv_histt: target image 
 histogram, hsvt: hsv image of the target image
 track_track=None
 Mask = cv2.calcBackProject([hsvt],[0,1],histm,[0,180,0,256],1)
 Open=cv2.morphologyEx(Mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel1)
 Filter=cv2.filter2D(Open,-1,kernel3,Open)
 Close=cv2.morphologyEx(Filter,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel1)
 _,thresh = cv2.threshold(Close,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
 #dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel1,iterations = 1)
 
 contours =cv2.findContours(Mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 if contours[2] is not None:
  cntss = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
  cnt=max(cntss, key=cv2.contourArea) 
  x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
  track_track=x,y,w,h
 return track_track,thresh
```

I found out that the method `cv2.filter2D` is what causes this lag at the detection moment (which is logical, since convolution is computationally cumbersome).

However, the Filtering step is very important for better detection result and that why i can't simply delete it.

The following image is with Filtering:
[image: Filter_2D]

the following image is without using the 2D-filtering
[image]

So, I'm just trying to make the overall performance (detection and tracking) smoother by just making the Filtering faster.

**So is there a way i can make this method works faster?**

resulted Mask image without any processing
[image]

Comment: I don't see why `filter2d()` would be any slower than morphological opening and closing. What are `kernel1` and `kernel3`?

Comment: @beaker. thanks for the reply. kernel1=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))--------kernel3=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))

Comment: Essentially all you're doing with the `filter2d()` is another dilation. Dilation sets a pixel's value to the max value within the kernel window, and filtering with a kernel of all 1's sets a pixel to a non-zero value if any of its neighbors are non-zero. You can try replacing `filter2d()` with `cv.dilate()` and see if you get similar results. If so, then you can break the `morphologyEx()` operations  into an erosion, followed by 3 iterations of dilation, followed by erosion.

Comment: @beaker. I've tried applying dilation instead of cv2.filter2D, it gives worse results. I've also tried your suggestion about doing dilation, followed by 3-iteration from dilation and then followed by erosion. It also doesn't give results that are at least same as Filter2D!

Comment: @beaker. I've not inserted the code that shows how i'm using the tracker since it is irrelevant to my question. However, i've applied the KCF-tracker directly from openCV I mean it is straight forward as you know

Comment: Can you post the `Mask` image that you're using so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @beaker. I've uploaded the Mask image

Comment: Your threshold is too high. Remove the `filter2d()` and change the threshold values from `10` to `1`. I also got good results using `erode()` for one iteration and `dilate()` for two iterations, but since I don't have the original image (I assume you're using the resulting image as a mask), I don't know how much to dilate it to get accurate results.

Comment: If you're using the erode/dilate option, you can also erode the entire image, find the bounding box and add some padding, then apply dilation to only this window. I'm also confused that you're finding the bounding box of the original `Mask` image, and that you're finding its axis-oriented bounding box rather than the `minAreaRect()` as I'd expect.

Comment: @beaker. I'm using the resulted binary image in order to find the contours in it and choose the one which represets my object according to some properties like e.g. rectangularity, area ratio etc. So the better the target object in the resulted binary mask the easier and more efficient i can filter it. Regarding your confusion  about the boudning box, i need the axis aligned bounding box becasue i must pass this bbox to the KCF-tracker as an initial roi to track and KCF accepts only an axis aligned bbox

Comment: @beaker. I didn't quite understand your suggestion about adding padding and then apply dilation to only the bbox wndow. I would be thankful if you could express that in an answer :)

Comment: @beaker. FYI, the bbox that i'm obtaining comes from the resulted binary image(after doing filer2D or morphological.etc). I'm afraid i can't do dilation only in the window of the bounding box since the bbox is obtained when the binary image is first improved